# Fundamental group of a genus-2 surface

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I want to calculate the fundamental group of a genus-2 surface, i.e. a double torus.

Using Van-Kampen I obtain ( with the notation generators- relations) $$\Pi_1(X,p) = < \alpha, \beta, \alpha_1, \beta_1 | \alpha \beta \alpha^{-1}\beta^{-1}, \ \alpha_1 \beta_1 \alpha_1^{-1}\beta_1^{-1}, \ \beta \beta_1^{-1} >$$

Is it correct ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is incorrect.

Let $[x, y] = xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ be the commutator of $x$ and $y$.

A genus $2$ surface can be constructed by starting with a wedge sum of $4$ circles $\{a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2\}$ and attaching a $2$-cell along $[a_1, b_1] [a_2, b_2]$. The fundamental group is then
$$
\langle a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2 \mid [a_1, b_1] [a_2, b_2]\rangle.
$$

The abelianization of this group is $\mathbb Z^4$. The abelianization of the group you have is $\mathbb Z^3$. Thus, they are different.

Comment: For a newbie in this area could you please explain what this notation of <{generators} | {some elements?}> means?

Comment: Am I right to say that since a genus-2 surface can be glued from an octagon (see, e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G1yyfPShgqw) and so reading from its boundary, $[a_1,b_1][a_2,b_2]$ can be retracted to a point, and thus the fundamental group as given above?